# How to address all except one

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avplayer

In my Swift iOS App I need to play different sounds quickly. Each triggered sound needs to stop all other so only one sounds plays at a time. 
I used

```
for player in audioPlayerBT{ player.stop()}
audioPlayerBT[playedNote].numberOfLoops = -1
audioPlayerBT[playedNote].play()
```

to stop all sounds before starting the new sound. That does work but there is a very very short pause. I would like to start the new sound before stopping the others to make it more fluent.

Can you except one index from

```
for player in audioPlayerBT{ player.stop()}
```

in order to use it after starting the new sound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to avoid stopping a particular player, consider:

```
for (index, player) in audioPlayerBT.enumerated() {
    if index != playedNote {
        player.stop()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, that looks like what I need, but it does not work. "Cannot call value of non-functional Type 'AudioPlayer' Recommended fix to delete () from audioPlayerBT() but without it I get: "Expression type '[AVAudioPlayer]' is ambiguous without more context"

Comment: @MarcelFriedmann Sorry, something got scrambled in copy & paste.  Trying again....

Comment: Thanks, thats it, you are a star!!

Comment: Or: `for (index, player) in audioPlayerBT.enumerated()  where index != playedNote { .. }`